# Performance analysis of Apache ignite

Tags: gridgain, ignite

How can we analyze performance of Apache ignite. **Task analysis** in ***ignitevisorcmd.sh*** only shows duration of task, its executions(whether its finished or not). Whereas **Node analysis** only shows snapshot of particular time instant for cpu, memory usage etc. I want to get cpu, disk, memory utilization of certain task over its time period. So how can I get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try to use [JMX MBeans](http://ignite.apache.org/releases/1.7.0/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/mxbean/package-summary.html) for monitoring Apache Ignite.

Or you may use [Visor GUI](https://gridgain.readme.io/docs/visor-gui) tool from GridGain Enterprise product.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this will be exactly what you need, but you should also check hosted management console for Ignite - https://console.gridgain.com/